# MutableArray loaded with a .plist file Boolean Value. How do I test whether True or False?

Tags: boolean, nsmutablearray, if-statement

I seem to have a problem understanding how to conditionally test a boolean value loaded from a .plist  to a mutablearray.  I simply dont understand what i am supposed to do and continue to receive an error: Passing argument 1 of 'numberWithBool:" makes integer from pointer without a cast.  any help understanding this is appreciated!

heres my code:

```
if ([NSNumber numberWithBool:[[self.ListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"TrueFalse"]]) {
    cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IsSelected.png"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `numberWithBool:` of `NSNumber` expects a boolean (BOOL) as its parameter.

`[[self.ListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"TrueFalse"]]` apearantly returns something other than BOOL.

To cast either an NSNumber or an NSString object to a boolean, you can use the `boolValue` method.

So, try and do the following:

```
if ([NSNumber numberWithBool:[[[self.ListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"TrueFalse"] boolValue]]) {
        cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IsSelected.png"]];
}
```

Comment: thx for your help.  i knew i wanted to cast but was struggling with syntax.  the odd thing i found that when my dictionary stores a YES for some reason i am testing in "IF" statement with a "!" NOT.  it works but seem opposite.  but for now i am going with it. thanks!